# Approach to pass key for crypto operations on chaincode interaction

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I see [fabric-shim-crypto](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-node/tree/master/fabric-shim-crypto) library for performing encyption & signing chaincode. This suggests to pass key through transient data.

I think about another approach in which we can add it as an custom attribute in the certificate during certicate generation. This way whenever user interact with the chaincode, key can be retrieved by accessing the certificate and perfrom related crypto operation.

Which approach will be better and what are the pros and cons of both.

Answer (score 0):

Second approach looks good , you can use attribute based access control lib in chaincode to achieve this